# Method as a properties in prototypes

Tags: javascript, oop, methods, properties, prototype

Is there any way to force a prototype's method (function) to be a property?

Say I have `Foo` with the method `bar`:

```
Foo.prototype.bar = function getBar() {
    return something
}
```

To call `bar`, I can simply call `foo.bar();`, However I want `bar` to be a property of Foo, not a method, meaning `foo.bar;`. To do so, I can simply make `getbar()` a self invoking function:

```
Foo.prototype.bar = (function getBar() {
    return something
})();
```

Now `.bar` is callable as a property. **BUT** the problem is that `bar` is only set when an instance of `Foo` is created, not every time `.bar` is called.

Is there any way I can get `getBar()` to be executed every time I  call `foo.bar`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get):

```
function Foo () {
    this.x = 1;
};

// Example of adding a getter to Foo.prototype
Object.defineProperty(Foo.prototype, 'bar', {
  get: function getBar () {
    return this.x++;
  }
});

var tmp = new Foo;

tmp.bar; // 1
tmp.bar; // 2
tmp.bar; // 3
```

Comment: Thanks! That's did it.